# What code to add into src/routes/patterns/<category>/<topic.ts>

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-redux

I'm a junior react developer and I got just recently to finish some project created by the react-native, which uses also redux.

Here is the project structure:

```
src/
├── App.js
├── Router.js
├── actionTypes
│   └── Structure.ts
├── actions
│   ├── Calculations.ts
│   └── Structure.ts
├── components
│   ├── category
│   │   ├── CategoryItem.tsx
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── Input.tsx
│   │   ├── Text.tsx
│   │   ├── TopBar.tsx
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── subcategory
│   │   ├── SubCategoryItem.tsx
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── topic
│       ├── TopicItem.tsx
│       └── index.ts
├── data
│   ├── Categories.ts
│   ├── SubCategories.ts
│   └── Topics.ts
├── reducers
│   ├── StructureReducer.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── routes
    ├── Category.tsx
    ├── SubCategory.tsx
    ├── Topic.tsx
    ├── index.ts
    └── patterns
        ├── some_category
        │   ├── some_topic.ts
```

In general, the app is designed in order to have categories, sub categories, and then topics and what is missing is the topic's content which I need to add.

Below is the code snippet for the `data/Topics.ts`:

```
export interface TopicInterface {
    background: Function,
    icon: Function,
    numColumns: number,
    data: TopicDataInterface
}

export interface TopicDataInterface {
    name: string,
    origin: string
}

const Topics: any = {
    some_category: {
        background: require('../images/backgrounds/background.png'),
        numColumns: 1,
        name: i18n.t('some_category'),
        data: [
            {
                name: i18n.t('some_topic'),
                origin: 'some_topic',
            }
        ]
    },

};

export default Topics;
```

And the `components/topic/TopicItem.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    ImageBackground,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    ImageStyle,
    ViewStyle,
    TextStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from "../common";
import {
    getSubCategoryItemDimensions,
} from "../../actions/Calculations";
import {TopicDataInterface} from "../../data/Topics";

interface Props {
    topic: TopicDataInterface,
    onTopicPress: Function
}

interface Style {
    container: ImageStyle,
    categoryNameContainer: ViewStyle,
    categoryName: TextStyle,
}

const TopicItem = ({topic, onTopicPress}: Props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => onTopicPress(topic.origin)}
    >
        <ImageBackground
            source={require('../../images/square.png')}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <View style={styles.categoryNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.categoryName}>
                    {topic.name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default TopicItem;


const styles = StyleSheet.create<Style>({
    container: getSubCategoryItemDimensions(),
    categoryNameContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    categoryName: {
        textAlign: 'center',
    }
});
```

So far I see that the interesting place would be the `routes/patterns/` dir.

I assume there should be the topics content, but the already existing file there is empty. No idea if it is the right place for that and how the final code should look like.

How to implement the topic's content?

Please let me know if should i share some more code here.